# Getting a "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" even though I am running it in a separate thread

Tags: java, android, html, multithreading

Have very little experience in Android Development, and am trying to pull HTML directly from a website. I have written code that works fine when running it just straight java, but i get an `"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"` when I try to run it through my app. Some googling has told me that I have to put it in a separate thread, which I believe I have done, but it's not helping. Here are my two different java class files, the first being the `MainActivity` and the second being my thread that is supposed to deal with getting the info from the website.

Here's the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView main = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main);
    WebsiteDealerino jbae = new WebsiteDealerino();
    jbae.start();
    }
}
```

And here's my thread file:

```
public class WebsiteDealerino extends Thread {

public void run(){
    try{
        WebsiteDealerino jbae = new WebsiteDealerino();
        String[] stuff = jbae.getQuestion();
        MainActivity.main.setText(stuff[0]);
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

public String[] getQuestion() {
    try {
        return parseHTML(getHTML("http://jbae.po8.org"));
    } catch (IOException error) {
        return new String[]{"Ran into an error" };
    }
}

public String getHTML(String websiteURL) {
    String content = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new URL(websiteURL).openConnection();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        content = scanner.next();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}

public String[] parseHTML(String rawHTML) throws IOException {
    String parsed = "";
    boolean relevant;
    String[] lines = rawHTML.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    for(String line : lines) {
        relevant = true;
        for (char piece : line.toCharArray()) {
            if (piece == '<')
                relevant = false;
        }
        if (relevant)
            parsed += "SPLIT" + line;
    }
    String old = parsed;
    parsed = "";
    String characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789./,+­ *!?|() :^~=";
    for (int i = 1; i < old.length(); i++) {
        int j = i - 1;
        if ((old.toCharArray()[i] == ' ' && !characters.contains(old.toCharArray()[j] + "")))
            parsed += "";
        else
            parsed += old.toCharArray()[i];
    }
    String fixed = "";
    for (char Char : parsed.toCharArray()) {
        if (characters.contains(Char + ""))
            fixed += Char;
    }
    String[] parts = fixed.split("SPLIT");
    int leng = parts.length;
    int lengt = leng - 2;
    String[] fixeds = new String[lengt];
    int i = 0;
    int empties = 0;
    for (String part : parts) {
        if (i + 2 < parts.length)
            if (part.length() <= 1)
                i++;
        fixeds[i] = parts[i + 2];
        empties++;
    }
    String[] finalized;
    if (empties > 0) {
        int len = fixeds.length;
        finalized = new String[len - empties];
        i = 0;
        for (String fixe : fixeds) {
            if (fixe.length() > 1) {
                finalized[i] = fixe;
                i++;
            }
        }
    } else
        finalized = fixeds;
    i = 0;
    for (String finale : finalized) {

        if (finale.contains("Answer")) {
            String answer = "";
            String sensible = "0123456789.-";
            for (char Char : finale.toCharArray()) {
                if (sensible.contains(Char + ""))
                    answer += Char;
            }
            finalized[i] = answer;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return finalized;
}
```

}

Any help would be very much appreciated. Tried a bunch of things so far and no luck. Wish I'd have kept track of what I've done better so I could tell you what hasn't worked better but it's probably something obvious anyways.

Here's what I believe to be the relevant part of the logcat:

```
07-20 21:56:59.919 21503-21503/com.bmassey.android.jbaeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.bmassey.android.jbaeapp, PID: 21503
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bmassey.android.jbaeapp/com.bmassey.android.jbaeapp.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                             at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                                             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
                                                                             at com.bmassey.android.jbaeapp.WebsiteDealerino.getHtml(WebsiteDealerino.java:53)
                                                                             at com.bmassey.android.jbaeapp.MainActivity.onPostCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1188)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

PS: The majority of this code is my awkward parsing through the HTML, and I know that most of it will not be helpful but I thought I might as well just put it all in here.

Comment: add `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }`

Comment: facing same problem yet ?

Comment: You can better use a asynctask for this. because this would not work since the main thread is the only one which can change layout relative stuff like
MainActivity.main.setText(stuff[0]); or use libaries which helps you in doing network calls